# Perform action after GET request Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am fairly new to Node-Express. I am using the [Express Router](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) for routing the request. What I am basically doing is a video view, then delete function.
This is my code.

```
router.get('/videodelete', function(req, res) {
// Some synchronous operation using sync-exec 
res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "text/html"
});
res.end('<video src="../video/video.mp4" controls></video>');
// response is sent. Now delete the file after the response is shown.
fs.unlink("../video/video.mp4");
})
```

I also tried fs.unlinkSync. In all these cases, the delete operation is happening before sending the response. I wish to trigger the delete operation only after sending response. Is there any way to perform this action only after sending the response?

Comment: Do you want client to be able to download video file before delete operation?

Comment: The video should just be loaded on the browser properly. It would be okay if client can download it. But it should be deleted from server just after playing.

Comment: "just after playing." Then I doubt you can do it with current approach. Here you only sending html chunk that has a video tag. Client has to process it first and fire another request to download the video to show (some time later).

Comment: The problem, I guess with my approach is that before the client process the request and fire another request to download the video, the video is getting deleted. I think it would be best approach if I can know that client have handled my request completely (played the video completely) and the client gives a callback that video is played (request is handled properly) and then delete the video. Is there a way to know that callback?

Comment: "Is there a way to know that callback?" I'm not aware of something like this built-in.  As of your question " I wish to trigger the delete operation only after sending response" There is `finish` event `res.on('finish', fs.unlink.bind(fs, '../video/video.mp4')` But it only knows about pending request (not the one to download video file)

Comment: I tried the `finish` event. Here also the file is getting deleted before playing as expected.

Comment: Exactly as I said. Simply because "playing" is **another** request.